# Fixed navbar no longer staying fixed after adding flexslider

Tags: html, css

I'm just beginning to learn HTML and CSS and have created a simple top navbar that remained fixed at the top of the page before I added a timed flexslider. After adding the slider, the navbar no longer stays fixed to the top of the viewport, even though I haven't changed my navbar CSS. Thanks in advance for any ideas!

My HTML is:

```
 <div class="top-bar">

   <section class="logo">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/logo.jpg" id="logo"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>   

    <section class="nav-bar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
```

And my CSS is:

```
.top-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 7.5%;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    display: inline-block;
}


#logo {
    width: 2.0vw;
    z-index:20;
}

.nav-bar {
    position: fixed;
    right: 27.5%;
    z-index: 15;
}
```

Thanks again for any help!

Comment: Can you create a demo so we can better understand the problem? (JSBin, Plunker, JSFiddle...) Thx!

Comment: I solved the problem by moving my main CSS stylesheet below the flexslider stylesheet when initializing. Thanks!

Comment: You did right! Most of the time, you want to include your own stylesheets after the ones from your libraries. So you can override the styles for customization. Another good example is when you want to personalize the Bootstrap default theme.